# Angular 2 Dynamically modify DOM element

Tags: angular

Here is [jQuery demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/sPLNVhppIXWL46779j4Y?p=preview) on what I want to do.

HTML :

```
<div class="open-close">
  <div class="open">
    I'm open <span class="opener">opener</span>
  </div>
  <div class="close">
    I'm close <span class="closer">closer</span>
    <div class="open-close">
      <div class="open">
        I'm inner open. <span class="opener">opener</span>
      </div>
      <div class="close">
        I'm inner close. <span class="closer">closer</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".close").hide();

  $(".opener").click(function() {
    let $this = $(this),
      $parent = $this.closest(".open-close"),
      $close  = $parent.children(".close");

    console.log($parent);

    $close.show();
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".closer", function() {
    let $this = $(this),
      $close  = $this.closest(".close");

    $close.hide();
  });
});
```

Now, I know that using jQuery with Angular 2 is not welcomed, so what is the Angular 2 way of doing this?

In my application, the server will send the HTML something like I provided in the demo, and expect the application will hide all the 'close' elements and open them on 'opener' is clicked. Currently, this is my design.

I thought giving "close" and "open" elements local variable, instead of 'data-id', then the child elements which are 'closer' and 'opener', respectively, using the local variable, to find its open/close counter part with same id then opening/closing it.

```
<div class="open" #data-id="1">
  I'm open <span class="opener" (click)="onOpenerClick(data-id)">opener</span>
</div>
<div class="close" #data-id="1">
  I'm close <span class="closer" (click)="onCloserClick(data-id)">closer</span>
  <div class="open" #data-id="2">
    I'm inner open. <span class="opener" (click)="onOpenerClick(data-id)">opener</span>
  </div>
  <div class="close" #data-id="2">
    I'm inner close. <span class="closer" (click)="onCloserClick(data-id)">closer</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really have no idea to do this in Angular 2. This [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ITylZfGVKIudsERhGcC1) is as far as I can get.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      I'm open. <span (click)="opened=true">opener</span>
      <div *ngIf="opened">
        I'm close <span (click)="opened=false">closer</span>
        <div>
          I'm inner open. <span (click)="opened2=true">opener</span>
          <div *ngIf="opened2">
            I'm inner close <span (click)="opened2=false">closer</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: ['span { color : blue }']
})
export class App {
  opened = false;
  opened2 = false;
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

But the HTML comes from server. Do I have to attach 'opened' ~ 'openedN' programmatically? I wish the child element could set its nearest parent's 'opened' state. Or is there any simpler method?

Comment: *the HTML comes from server*: that's the main problem. The HTML should be in your template. You should get JSON from the server, not HTML.

Comment: @JBNizet In my application, I use <div [innerHTML]='displayed_html'>. I haven't tested it where the displayed_html contains angular stuff but it works well with regular html. But for now, even that doesn't work I want to know how to make the jQuery demo to work in Angular. I'll edit my question if necessary. Currently I'm reading the [Attribute Directive document](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) hoping this works.

Comment: No, using innerHTML won't compile the HTML and apply angular directives. The idea of angular is to precompile all the templates, preferrably at build time, using the AOT compiler. Why do you download HTML from the backend rather than JSON?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm trying to make my own CMS where I save all my contents in markdown. I thought requesting all of these markdowns would take a long time, so I request only the selected markdown, and the my other simple server sends the requested markdown.

Comment: I decided to convert markdown to HTML on this server. Then Angular server receives this HTML, and puts it into the 'displayed_html' (previous comment). And this works. And now I want to add 'open/close' feature to this markdown. My other server will convert this open/close markdown to HTML. If my client side would've used jQuery, I would've went with the way I provided in the demo.

Comment: Then you don't have much choice, and you should do with angular the same kind of thing you're doing with jQuery: search for elements by class in the DOM, an add event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I found three ways of doing this.

1. [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) ... [plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mkXY0piLWZ0e2s8DaeiN?p=preview)
2. [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html) ... [plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ycMrd1Erxt8H5nAYcyIC?p=preview)
3. [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) ... [plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/tSCK7rRoVzTM3BDJ8n0R?p=preview)

ElementRef is unsecure and makes code imcompatible with Web Worker according to [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html).

## ElementRef

ElementRef.nativeElement returns native element that you can just apply an event like you do in JavaScript.

```
this.el.nativeElement.onclick = function() {
  alert('hi');
}
```

compared to [javascript](https://plnkr.co/edit/0uqar5NFqOtRHsb5rdk9?p=preview):

```
document.getElementById('target').onclick = function() {
   alert('hi');
}
```

## Renderer

Angular suggests Renderer that instead of using ElementRef "take a look at Renderer which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported" from ElementRef documentation.

```
let target_el = this.el.nativeElement;

this.renderer.listen(target_el, "click", function() {
  alert('hi..');
});
```

As you can see from the demo, `this.el` in ElementRef example and Renderer example are the same.

- *I honestly don't know how using renderer is safer when they both use the same `this.el`. But I assume that using a renderer method like `renderer.listen` to attach an event to the DOM notifies Angular to pay attention to that target_el's input or something while DIRECT access to DOM leaves no chance to notify Angular. Please comment if you know how it works. I'm happy to edit question.*

## DOM Sanitizer

Use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` to prevent some attributes that Angular strips away. Angular strips away Angular event bidning and Html event attributes. You can try commenting the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` in the demo above, and it will give you

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

---

In my case, because I was getting the HTML from server, so I had to wait one tick before doing this:

```
.subscribe( html => {
    setTimeout( () => {
        this.html_area = html;

        // do dynamically adding event thing
    )}
})
```